# matplotlib path contains_point with latitude / longitude

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use matplotlib Path.contains_point using latitude / longitude for vertices and point.

Do I need to do some sort of transform on the lat/lon pairs to make this work properly?  The example seems to work ok, but I want to make sure I get this right for all cases.

If I need to do a transform, how?

```
def point_in_poly(vertices, x, y)
    from matplotlib.path import Path as mpPath

    path =mpPath(vertices)
    point = (x,y)
    return path.contains_point(point)

vertices = [(146.0,-42.0),(147.0,-42.0),(147.0,-43.0), (146.0,-43.0)]
print(point_in_poly(vertices, 146.5, -42.5)
```

Thanks

Comment: The coordinates of your path and point on which you test should be in *the same* coordinate system. So if you tranform your path, you should also transform the point before testing.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rutger.  My main concern is whether I have to do any sort of spherical transform on path and point or just let matplotlib do the magic.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542843/inpolygon-for-python-examples-of-matplotlib-path-path-contains-points-method