# inpolygon - Examples of matplotlib.path.Path contains_points() method?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

I have been searching for a python alternative to MATLAB's `inpolygon()` and I have come across `contains_points` as a good option.

However, the docs are a little bare with no indication of what type of data `contains_points` expects:

> `contains_points(points, transform=None, radius=0.0)`
>
> Returns a `bool` array which is `True` if the path contains the corresponding point.
>
> If transform is not `None`, the path will be transformed before performing the test.
>
> radius allows the path to be made slightly larger or smaller.

I have the polygon stored as an `n`*2 numpy array (where `n` is quite large ~ 500). As far as I can see I need to call the `Path()` method on this data which seems to work OK:

```
poly_path = Path(poly_points)
```

At the moment I also have the points I wish to test stored as another `n`*2 numpy array (catalog_points).

Perhaps my problem lies here? As when I run:

```
in_poly = poly_path.contains_points(catalog_points)
```

I get back an `ndarray` containing `False` for every value no matter the set of points I use (I have tested this on arrays of points well within the polygon).

Comment: For what it's worth, this works as expected for me: `p = Path([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]); result = p.contains_points([[0.1, 0.1], [1, 1], [0.5, 0.6], [0.5, 0.4]])`.  I get an array containing `[True, False, False, True]`, as expected.  However, if I use `p = Path([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]], closed=True)`, `result` is all False.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a self-contained example (i.e. something we can copy and run) that does not work as expected?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Often in these situations, I find the source to be illuminating...

We can see the source for [`path.contains_point`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/714d18788320325d0bff75184f62d472f67ceb91/lib/matplotlib/path.py#L483) accepts a container that has at least 2 elements.  The source for `contains_points` is a bit harder to figure out since it calls through to a C function [`Py_points_in_path`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/382974186f78ef53cc91f7cf161159d5d9f71475/src/_path_wrapper.cpp#L61).  It seems that this function accepts a iterable that yields elements that have a length 2:

```
>>> from matplotlib import path
>>> p = path.Path([(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])  # square with legs length 1 and bottom left corner at the origin
>>> p.contains_points([(.5, .5)])
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Of course, we could use a numpy array of points as well:

```
>>> points = np.array([.5, .5]).reshape(1, 2)
>>> points
array([[ 0.5,  0.5]])
>>> p.contains_points(points)
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

And just to check that we aren't always just getting `True`:

```
>>> points = np.array([.5, .5, 1, 1.5]).reshape(2, 2)
>>> points
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 1. ,  1.5]])
>>> p.contains_points(points)
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Good example of unit testing / teaching, checking for positive AND negative

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the vertices are ordered as wanted. Below vertices are ordered in a way that the resulting path is a pair of triangles rather than a rectangle. So, `contains_points` only returns `True` for points inside any of the triangles.

```py
>>> p = path.Path(np.array([bfp1, bfp2, bfp4, bfp3]))
>>> p
Path([[ 5.53147871  0.78330843]
 [ 1.78330843  5.46852129]
 [ 0.53147871 -3.21669157]
 [-3.21669157  1.46852129]], None)
>>> IsPointInside = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 9]])
>>> IsPointInside
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 9]])
>>> p.contains_points(IsPointInside)
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

The output for the first point would have been `True` if `bfp3` and `bfp4` were swapped.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this function to return a array as in `matlab` `inpolygon` function. But this will return only the points that are inside the given polygon. You can't find the points in the edge of the polygon with this function.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import path

def inpolygon(xq, yq, xv, yv):
    shape = xq.shape
    xq = xq.reshape(-1)
    yq = yq.reshape(-1)
    xv = xv.reshape(-1)
    yv = yv.reshape(-1)
    q = [(xq[i], yq[i]) for i in range(xq.shape[0])]
    p = path.Path([(xv[i], yv[i]) for i in range(xv.shape[0])])
    return p.contains_points(q).reshape(shape)
```

You can call the function as:

```
xv = np.array([0.5,0.2,1.0,0,0.8,0.5])
yv = np.array([1.0,0.1,0.7,0.7,0.1,1])
xq = np.array([0.1,0.5,0.9,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.6,0.8,0.7,0.2])
yq = np.array([0.4,0.6,0.9,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.2,0.6])
print(inpolygon(xq, yq, xv, yv))
```

As in the [`matlab` documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) this function,

> returns in indicating if the query points specified by xq and yq are inside <s>or on the edge</s> of the polygon area defined by xv and yv.

Comment: That is awesome Ramesh Thank you! I use it now

Comment: This answer definitely deserves more upvotes. +1 for sharing a function that *almost* matches the Matlab function!