# How to find the logic/algorithm behind matplotlib.path.Path()

Tags: python, matplotlib, path

Is there any references, algorithm, the mathematical equations/logic behind the **matplotlib.path.contains_point(points)**.

I have looked into background source code but found nothing.
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.2/lib/matplotlib/path.py#L24-L1039

My code looks like this

```
 #for point inside polygon 
 #The ploygon
 polygon_2=list(zip(MRds, NRds))
 #the point 
 points_2 =(MEds,NEds)
 #finding if the point is inside the polygon or not
 path = matplotlib.path.Path(polygon_2)
 inside = path.contains_point(points_2)
```

Comment: Here is the [implementation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/921e9ac89cecf309abeea656f1835f244e189417/src/_path.h#L108).

Comment: have a look at the answer to this question for sample code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542843/inpolygon-examples-of-matplotlib-path-path-contains-points-method

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thanks alot. I guess i have some directional sense.

Comment: @ChrisSeeling thanks it had some directions